# What is the difference between using API permissions and using Authorized Client Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have been using Azure AD for over 4 years now and just today I saw that I could add "Authorized client applications" under Explore an API when I am setting up an application in Azure Entra ID (formerly Azure AD).

I have always been using API permissions when a client app needs to access APIs exposed by a different app. The way I would have been doing this is by having 2 apps registered in Entra, one of them exposing some scopes (and or App roles) and the other one having this scope under API permissions. I will almost always provide admin consent over this scope. I am putting some screenshots below to show how it looks like.

[image: Setting scopes of an exposed API]
Setting scopes of an exposed API

[image: The App using the scope as a permission]
The App using the scope as a permission

Then I noticed a few hours back that I can authorize client applications in the same screen as exposing the API scopes. But I have no idea what this does and how different this is from what I have been doing. What kind of use case should I use this feature instead of adding permissions in my client applications?

Answer (score 0):

**API permissions** are used to grant access to specific scopes or permissions that are defined by the API. The user or administrator is requested to provide consent when a client application seeks access to the API, specifying the scopes or permissions that it requires.

- The client application can use the designated scopes or permissions to access the API when approval has been given.

For **sample**, I granted `user_impersonation` API permission that is defined by Azure Service Management API that allows access to the API as users:

[image]

**Authorized client applications** means that the client application is trusted by the API, when client calls the API they will not need to consent.

For **sample**, In ***Single tenant***, the user will be able to directly login without providing any consent when the `ServerApp` API is called by the `ClientApp` if the `ClientApp` is added as Authorized client applications:

[image]

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=api://ServerAppID/test.read
&state=12345
```

[image]

In **multitenant** scenarios, I created an `ClientApp` and added `ServerApp` API permissions like below:

[image]

Now when I tried to sign-in to the application using other tenant user, I got the error:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=api://ServerAppID/test.read
&state=12345
```

> AADSTS650052 The app is trying to access a service xxx(ServerApp) that your organization xxx lacks a service principal for. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions or consent to the application in order to create the required service principal.

[image]

In this scenario, adding the `ClientApp` as the **Authorized client applications** in the `ServerApp` is mandatory.

After adding , **the user is now able to successfully login:**

[image]

[image]